# Cannot merge node using null property even if there'are not null values

Tags: neo4j

I want to create my first project in Neo4j and I was trying to import data from a csv file.

The data looks like this:

`category, film, name, winner(y/n), year`

My table doesn't have null values or empty rows. When I tried this statement, it gave me the following error:

> Cannot merge node using null property value for value

However, I don't have null in the year column.

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file:///golden_globe.csv" AS row WITH { category: row[0], film: row[1], nomination_name: row[2],
   winner: row[3], year: row[4]} AS data

SKIP 1 
MERGE (y:Year {value:data.year})
MERGE (c:Category {name: data.category})
MERGE (n:Nomination {name: data.nomination_name})
MERGE (m:Movie {title: data.film})
CREATE (a:Golden_Globe) SET a = data
CREATE (c)<-[:IN_CATEGORY]-(a)-[:IN_YEAR]->(y)
CREATE (a)-[:NOMINATED]->(n), (a)-[:FOR_MOVIE]->(m)
MERGE (n)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m)
WITH * WHERE data.winner = "yes" SET a:Winners;
```

What is causing the error?

Comment: looks fine... try `RETURN data.year` and see the results, that will maybe give you any hint

Comment: Can you share your CSV file?

Comment: how did u solve this? i am facing the same